# Prove equality with eq_rect without UIP

Tags: coq

How do I prove a dependent equality without extra axioms or appealing
to the decidable equality of `nat`?  Furthermore, how do I rewrite the
proof term type and goal simultaneously to work with type checking?

I have a simple, toy problem.
Show that in a dependent type `toy` appending adds to the dependent part.
This is conceptually simple, but difficult to prove within the language.

```
Require Import Arith.

Axiom toy : nat -> Prop.
Axiom toy_S : forall n, toy n -> toy (S n).

Definition toy_plus (n i : nat) (w : toy n) : toy (i + n).
  induction i; [ apply w | ].
  apply (toy_S _ IHi).
Defined.

Theorem toy_regroup (i j n : nat) (le_ji : j <= i) : i - j + (j + n) = i + n.
  induction le_ji; [ rewrite Nat.sub_diag; apply eq_refl | ].
  rewrite (Nat.sub_succ_l _ _ le_ji).
  simpl; rewrite IHle_ji; apply eq_refl.
Qed.

Theorem toy_append (n i j : nat) (le_ji : j <= i) (w : toy n) :
    toy_plus n i w = eq_rect _ toy (toy_plus (j+n) (i-j) (toy_plus n j w)) _ (toy_regroup i j n le_ji).
(* ??? *)
```

Looking for examples, people often use Strecher K / UIP to ignore the proof part.
Since `nat` has decidable equality, we can use `eq_rect_eq_dec`, which does work.
Though, it's still not quite trivial.

```
Require Import Coq.Logic.Eqdep_dec.

Theorem toy_append (n i j : nat) (le_ji : j <= i) (w : toy n) :
    toy_plus n i w = eq_rect _ toy (toy_plus (j+n) (i-j) (toy_plus n j w)) _ (toy_regroup i j n le_ji).
  generalize (toy_regroup i j n le_ji) as eqin.
  induction le_ji.
    (* We need to rewrite both the proof and goal simultaneously. *)
    rewrite Nat.sub_diag; intros.
    (* Thanks to UIP, we don't care exactly which proof was used and can simplify away eq_rect. *)
    rewrite <- (eq_rect_eq_dec Nat.eq_dec); apply eq_refl.
(* ... *)
```

Here, it hides the proof in `eq_rect`, then leaves it in the goal so it can rewrite both the
proof type and the type using it simultaneously to get the correct type out.
Trying to do it piecewise is ill-typed.

Other libraries I've looked at such as
[https://ropas.snu.ac.kr/~gil.hur/Heq/doc/src.Heq.html](https://ropas.snu.ac.kr/%7Egil.hur/Heq/doc/src.Heq.html)
also seem to work this way, using an extra axiom or decidability.

**The question:**

How do I prove `toy_append` without extra axioms or appealing
to the decidability of equality in `nat`?  That is, I'm trying
to write a direct proof.  Since I am proving it based on the same
structure that the function is using, I think that it should be possible?
Especially, how do I change the type proof term in `eq_rect` and
simultaneously change the type on the rest of the goal?  Once I can
do that, I should be able to proof that, because the proof is the
same, and now that the types are the same, the equality proof is `eq_refl`,
and the `eq_rect` can be simplified away.

Trying to use `le_ind` fails because the `le_ji` term is used in
the proof part of `eq_rect`.  That can be worked around with

```
Scheme le_dep_ind := Induction for le Sort Prop.

Theorem toy_append (n i j : nat) (le_ji : j <= i) (w : toy n) :
    toy_plus n i w = eq_rect _ toy (toy_plus (j+n) (i-j) (toy_plus n j w)) _ (toy_regroup i j n le_ji).
  induction le_ji using le_dep_ind.
    (*
The follow tactics fail due to not rewriting the whole term, including the dependent part.
rewrite Nat.sub_diag.
Error: Cannot refine with term
 "eq_ind_r
    (fun _ : nat =>
     toy_plus n j w =
     eq_rect (j - j + (j + n)) toy
       (toy_plus (j + n) (j - j) (toy_plus n j w)) 
       (j + n) (toy_regroup j j n (le_n j))) ?M1070 
    (Nat.sub_diag ?M1066)" because a metavariable has several occurrences.

rewrite Nat.sub_diag at 1.
Error: build_signature: no constraint can apply on a dependent argument
*)
```

But, this still leaves the question of how to simplify both
the proof term's type and the rest of the goal simulaneously
so it type checks.

Is there a recommended way to represent these types of equalities?
For example, the library mentions using `JMeq` and `eq_dep` instead of `eq_rect`
and has their own approach with `existT ... = existT ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heterogeneous equalities are sometimes easier with `eq_dep` than with `_ = eq_rect _ _`, since you don't need to prove the equality on indices separately and then reason about how that behaves.

```
Require Import Arith Eqdep.

Axiom toy : nat -> Prop.
Axiom toy_S : forall n, toy n -> toy (S n).

Definition toy_plus (n i : nat) (w : toy n) : toy (i + n).
Proof.
  induction i; [ apply w | ].
  apply (toy_S _ IHi).
Defined.

Lemma f_eq_dep' (U V : Type) (P : U -> Type) (R : V -> Type) (p q : U) (x : P p) 
    (y : P q) (g : U -> V) (f : forall p0 : U, P p0 -> R (g p0))
  : eq_dep U P p x q y -> eq_dep V R (g p) (f p x) (g q) (f q y).
Proof.
  intros []; reflexivity.
Qed.

Theorem toy_append (n i j : nat) (le_ji : j <= i) (w : toy n) :
  eq_dep nat toy _ (toy_plus n i w) _ (toy_plus (j+n) (i-j) (toy_plus n j w)).
Proof.
  induction le_ji.
  - rewrite Nat.sub_diag; cbn. reflexivity.
  - rewrite Nat.sub_succ_l by assumption; cbn.
    apply f_eq_dep'.
    apply IHle_ji.
Qed.
```

(Edit from asker to summarize comments below)

`eq_dep` and `eq_rect` are interchangeable by

```
Theorem eq_dep_rect (A : Type) (a b : A) (P : A -> Type) (Pa : P a) (Pb : P b) (eqd : eq_dep _ P _ Pa _ Pb) :
    { eq_ab : a = b & Pb = eq_rect a P Pa b eq_ab}.
  simple refine (let eq_ab : a = b := _ in _); [ destruct eqd; apply eq_refl | ].
  apply (existT _ eq_ab).
  destruct eqd; apply eq_refl.
Qed.

Theorem eq_rect_dep (A : Type) (a b : A) (P : A -> Type) (Pa : P a) (Pb : P b) (eq_ab : a = b)
    (eqr : Pb = eq_rect a P Pa b eq_ab) : eq_dep A P a Pa b Pb.
  destruct eq_ab; rewrite eqr; apply eq_dep_intro.
Qed.
```

which puts the proof from `eq_dep` into `eq_rect`.  Depending on whether the proof matches, you could still end up needing UIP to replace the proof.

Comment: Ah, that's neat that for eq_dep phrasing has essentially the same proof as just the toy_regroup by itself.  As I understand it, _ = eq_rect _ implies eq_dep, but not the other way around.  This approach makes sense to be practical.  But, I'm still curious about the original question: is the eq_rect form provable directly, and what logical machinery is needed to do it?

Comment: `eq_dep` does imply `_ = eq_rect _`. The most general implication holds with decidable equality on indices (here `nat`). And without decidable equality, you just don't get to choose the equality proof in `_ = eq_rect _`. But in this case, the equality proof extracted from `toy_append` probably coincides with `toy_regroup` anyway.

Comment: Ah,  I see what you're saying.  You can take the implicit (a=b) in eq_dep, and use that to generate a eq_rect.  So, putting that together, you can prove everything with eq_dep, then convert to eq_rect if needed.  So, eq_rect <-> eq_dep.

Require Import Eqdep.
Theorem eq_dep_rect (A : Type) (a b : A) (P : A -> Type) (Pa : P a) (Pb : P b) (eqd : eq_dep _ P _ Pa _ Pb) :
    { eq_ab : a = b & Pb = eq_rect a P Pa b eq_ab}.
  simple refine (let eq_ab : a = b := _ in _); [ destruct eqd; apply eq_refl | ].
  apply (existT _ eq_ab).
  destruct eqd; apply eq_refl.
Qed.

That solves it!